# Transformer Going Up In Voltage Over Time

Tags: voltage, transformer

I have a transformer from a 1953 jukebox that seems to be increasing in voltage over time.  When I first got it, it was outputting 32V.  A week later it seemed steady at 38V, then 45V.  Now I just measured it and it's at 50V.

I see no visible signs of burning or excessive heat and I've not seen or smelled any smoke.

It is supposed to be a 115V => 32V (approx) transformer.

What is going on?  Do I need to throw this thing out?

[image]

Comment: I guess that could happen if the primary windings were shorting out one-by-one. I don't know  how *likely* that is. Are you testing the transformer by itself or is there a circuit connected to it?

Comment: Check the battery in your multimeter. Seems like it might be going flat.

Comment: Could it be old/weakening battery in the DMM causing incorrect measurements? As a test, if you measure a AA battery and instead of 1.5V it reads 2.3V, that's the problem.

Comment: Welcome. Are you tracking the AC input voltage as well? This can and will vary with time.

Comment: What kind of DMM are you using to make these measurements? Some very low quality DMMs are not rated for measuring 110VACrms line voltage safely. Peak 110VAC voltage is more like 170V peak. And 48V DC is considered the highest "safe" DC voltage.

Comment: Wow - those were fast responses!  To answer some of your questions:
- The DMM is an Equus 3320.  Will replace batteries and see what that does. - The transformer is in a circuit, though I can easily isolate it.  Will do that and make sure I'm getting the same results.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

@brhans was correct above - once I replaced my batteries I started getting stable readings out of this transformer.  Thanks everyone